# SQL issue when merging two databases with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, merging-data

I have a database at a workspace A and workspace B. 
Online there is a copy of this database which is always updated from both workspaces. 
Also both workspaces can need to update their databases whenever the other workspace makes any changes.

Everything is working well but my problem is this: for example there are 2 tables `Stock` and `Orders`, in `Orders` there is a column which is the `stock_id`.

If workspace A creates a new "Stock X" with an automatically incremented "stock_id"=23 and workspace B creates a new "Stock Y" with an automatically incremented "stock_id" = 23, workspace B will add workspace A's "Stock X" and workspace B will add workspace B's "Stock Y" but each will have a different id in each database.

The problem occurs when workspace A makes an order on stock_id=23 which is "Stock X", when this query is sent to the central database, and then sent to workspace B, it will insert the order but stock_id = 23 will refer to "Stock Y".

I would really appreciate some help with this thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

Your original design used `AUTO INCREMENT` columns for the primary key.  The problem with this is, that as you're seeing when you have data simultaneously going into separate databases that will eventually be merged, you end up creating duplicate keys.

One alternate is to use a sequence in each distinct database.  Unfortunately, sequences are not natively available in mysql (many other db's such as Oracle, db2 do have them -- they allow this type of distributed database inserts w/o collisions).  `AUTO INCREMENT` columns don't allow the kind of replication you want.

So, you're left with two options.

1) Add an extra part of the primary key that sets the location_id (as per the first answer).

2) Or generate your id's for your inserts by hand using your own sequence, rather than using `AUTO INCREMENT` columns.

It's probably best to implement a sequence as a stored proc/function that commits itself when it gets the next value in the sequence -- this may end up with values not being used.  That's fine -- it's better than the contention if you were to wait to commit a sequence number until the entire insert committed.

The main thing is that when you're doing the first insert, you use the sequence # from a stored proc.  When you effectively replicate the data into the 2nd db, you use the generated sequence # in the row from the originating db.  And the sequence would be maintained in each separate db w/ different starting points to prevent collisions.

For example, in each database, you would want two pieces:

1)  a table that holds the next available sequence number for each named sequence.  (each table that gets a primary key drawn from a sequence gets an entry).
2)  a function that accesses and updates that table w/ the next sequence number.

A sample implementation would be:

Sequence table:

```
CREATE TABLE sequences (
  name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  value int(10) unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Sequence Function(s):

```
delimiter //
create function get_next_value(p_name varchar(30)) returns int
  deterministic
  sql security invoker
begin
  declare current_val integer;
    UPDATE sequences
    SET value = (@current_val:=value) + 1
    WHERE name = p_name;

  return @current_val;
end //
delimiter ;
```

The main issue is that the stored function needs to be a single statement, so that it completes and therefore commits immediately (otherwise, you'll have a lock on it that will cause your transactions to stack up behind each other as orders come in.  If you don't have very high throughput, this isn't as much of an issue.

I didn't write this function -- I'm liberally copying it from here:   http://www.bigdbahead.com/?p=185  where I would refer you to, for more details.  (And if that user ever finds me here, I'll be happy to let him write an answer and give him the appropriate credit here also).

Now, for each database, you initialize the value with a different number to avoid collisions.  So, for the `orders` table, in location A, you'd initialize this with:

```
insert into sequences ('orders', 1);
```

and in location B, you'd initialize this with:

```
insert into sequences ('orders', 1000000);
```

And then in both databases, on an insert into `orders`, you'd do:

```
insert into orders (order_id, . . .)
select mysql.get_next_value('user_id'), . . . <hardcoded-values>
```

--

I haven't road-tested this solution -- take it as an outline of the what I was suggesting in my answer regarding sequences.  You should follow-up on the blog entry link above, which provides some more details, specifically on how this work under transaction control, see the comments (where I've taken a form of the function from the comments, not the original function), and of course, test it under load.

Comment: Even though Im sure that I wont run into a collision, atleast not before a couple of light years. However assigning different auto increment roots wont solve my problem.
For example: structure: Stock(s_id,s_name) Orders(o_id,s_id,amount)
workspace A inserts a new item s1, it is assigned an auto increment s1.s_id = 1, then it makes an order O with o.s_id = 1, when it sends these two queries to workspace 2, it inserts the stock s1 and it is assigned an auto increment s1.s_id = 100000, then it executes the second query "insert into Orders(s_id) values (1)". I think there is no logical solution

Comment: My apologies -- see revised answer.  I as thinking in db2 terms (my current client), rather than mysql terms.  And in general, yes, there are logical solutions to this issue -- it was quite common in the days before wi-fi & pervasive internet connections, to have db's that were distributed and had to have their data merged later.  Thus, there are plenty of schemes to avoid collisions upon merge.

Comment: Yes i am interested. I would appreciate a small example cause I got a little lost. And I would appreciate your thoughts on what I came up with below

Comment: @Haz  Sorry it took me so long to update.  I've been under the weather and only now coming back online.  How it helps some to explain what I meant, even if you go in a different direction.

Comment: Thank you again Mike Ryan. I've read your answer more than 3 times and Im sure it is the answer Im looking for and here is what I have managed to understand from the above: 

When inserting a new order for item_id=22 and item_name ='A', we do it this way : insert into orders(stock_id) values (select stock_id from stock where stock_item='A'),  order_id will be auto incremental and they can have different seeds making sure no collisions. But I dont see why we need to introduce collisions, we can stick with auto_increment. Im probably not making any sense

Answer (score 2):

If workspace A and B each have different entries for ID 23, then your only option would be to create a secondary key for each entry when the records are updated to the central DB. This key could then be recopied back to the workspace databases when you update them, which would allow their items to be accessed with a truly unique identifier.

I would strongly suggest that you not use this method, however!

The proper way to do things would be to create a web or desktop application used at workspaces 1 and 2, which would connect to the central database and use it for all data access. Good database design generally means having as few duplicate copies of data as possible. By having multiple copies of orders, stock etc. kicking around in three different databases you are setting yourself up for data corruption and/or loss in the future--a problem which will only become more and more difficult to repair as your database grows in size. Fix the structural problem now before the database gets any bigger!

Comment: Could you please give me a simple example of your secondary key solution. 
I would use a central database, but the workspaces are connected through internet, not LAN, and they cannot afford the time lag. As for my data structure, its probably as simply implemented as foreign keys examples can be. Stock(stock_id,name,etc) Orders(o_id,stock_id,amount,etc). What would you suggest. Thanks again

Comment: I rethought the problem and here's what I can give you. My original solution was to have two ids, id_local and id_global. Id_local is auto-assigned in the local database upon record creation. Id_global is auto-assigned in the global database when the records are copied over. If every time an update is made the records are updated back to the workspace databases, then this id_global will end up being present in those databases as well and could be used to uniquely identify each record. Other solution in next comment.

Comment: My other solution would be to have a workspace id column and a multi-column key on id_workspace, and the auto-assigned item id. That way, workspace 1 and 2 could auto-assign the same values without having overlapping ids/pks because they would be uniquely identified through the workspace id column as well. I really suggest you implement a centralised database solution if at all possible, because something is going to break sooner or later, leaving you with a bunch of unhappy customers. That said, if you absolutely cannot do that, then this idea may end up working for you.

Comment: Could you give me a simple example on your second solution. And I would like to know what you think of my answer below

Comment: A stock table would look as follows: id_stock, id_workspace, name... The id_workspace is simply there to identify from which auto-increment set the variables come. That is to say, it differentiates the record with the auto-increment value 23 created in workspace A from the record with the auto-increment value 23 created in workspace B. I have a hard time with your answer because you are basically saying workspace A sends its queries to the central DB before execution. Why not just do this with every query and that way you would avoid the whole dis-continuum of information altogether?

Comment: I improved my answer.. I understand your solution, but I can't see how it can be implemented to solve my problem

Comment: The problem occurs when workspace A makes an order on stock_id=23 which is "Stock X", when this query is sent to the central database, and then sent to workspace B, it will insert the order but stock_id = 23 will refer to "Stock Y". - If the stock item has an id_workspace attached to it, then you can distinguish the two items. The rest you're going to have to figure out for yourself based on the structure of your applications.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this answer, but Im still confused if its better to go with it than with the other solutions above. 
All queries in workspace B are executed immidiatly on the local database and also sent to the central database and then sent to workspace A, however queries on workspace A are not immidiatly executed on the local database, they are sent to the central database then the central sends them to workspace B, and when workspace B executes these queries, then it notifies the central and then workspace A is notified, then it can execute the queries which were stored. So that way workspace B is allowed to execute its queries normally, but workspace A is only allowed to execute its queries only when it knows when workspace B has executed those queries, since before workspace B executes the queries of A, it sends its own new queries, and then executes the queries of A, so after  A is notified that B executed its queries, it checks if B sent any new queries of its own and executes them then it executes its own queries. That way all autoincrememted id's will be the same in both workspaces. Example:

Workspace A:

```
         q1= insert into stock (name) values ('A')    not executed

         q2= insert into stock (name) values ('B')    not executed
```

Database of A:  (EMPTY)

Workspace A sends q1 & q2 to central and is the waiting for central to confirm that B has executed those queries so it can execute them itself

Workspace B:

```
         q3= insert into stock (name) values ('C')    executed id=1

         q4= insert into stock (name) values ('D')    executed id=2
```

Database of B: (1,'C') , (2,'D')

Workspace B after sending q3 & q4 to central, it is notified of q1 and q2,

Workspace B executes q1 & q2

```
          q1= insert into stock (name) values ('A')   executed id=3

          q2= insert into stock (name) values ('B')   executed id=4
```

Database B: (1,'C') , (2,'D'), (3,'A') , (4,'B')

Workspace A is notified that B has executed its q1 & q2, but it is told that it must execute q3 & q4 before it can execute q1 & q2

Workspace A:

```
          q3= insert into stock (name) values ('C')    executed id=1

          q4= insert into stock (name) values ('D')    executed id=2

          q1= insert into stock (name) values ('A')    executed id=3

          q2= insert into stock (name) values ('B')    executed id=4
```

Database of B: (1,'C') , (2,'D'), (3,'A') , (4,'B')

Comment: My main comment about the above, is that you would be baking your architecture directly into your code, which is not very extendable/flexible.  Both of our solutions above, which go in different directions, would be extendable to multiple distributed databases.  And neither would be negatively effected if one of the databases (including the central database where everything gets merged) was down.  Regardless of which way you go, I'd encourage you to think in those terms -- would it work w/ 1 db, 2 db's and 10 db's.  And what happens when one or more db's is down.